# Date.today() gives different dates on different classes

Tags: apex, datetime, date, timezone

These are the two classes I have written:

**aura:component controller class**

```
public class ResourcesComponentClass {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void getDate(){
        Datetime dateObj = Date.today();
        System.debug(dateObj.date());
    }
}
```

**Rest Resource class**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/AllHistory/*')
global class ExternalAllResourcesApi {
    @HttpPut
    global static String updateDateAndTime() {
        Datetime dateObj = Date.today();
        System.debug(dateObj.date());
    }
}
```

First one is `aura:component` controller class and the second is a `Rest Resource` class. I am calling `dateObj.date()` from both the classes. The problem is that the first `dateObj.date()` returns `2020-08-20`and the second returns `2020-08-21`, even if the second class is run minutes after first class. So, why is this happening like this?

**What should I do if I want same dates in both the classes?** By the way, current date is `2020-08-21`.

Answer (score 3):

I can make an assumption, that those two pieces of the code are running by two different users, and those users have different time zone is settings.
According to the documentation of [Date.today()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) method:

> Returns the current date in **the current user's time zone**.

---

if you want to get today value of GMT, use `Datetime` class

```
Datetime.now().dateGMT();
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. I will check this out. But, these are not from different time zones. They are both from same org in same laptop.

Comment: when I am saying "users have different timezones", I mean [salesforce time zone setting.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332378&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: Even after using `Datetime.now().dateGMT()`, i am getting different dates.

Comment: @JayeshBabu I think you are missing something. I have just tested and `Datetime.now().dateGMT()` returns the correct date for different user time zones. I have tested it now for the user with +14 time zone, and it displays correctly `DEBUG|2020-08-21 00:00:00`  please add code, that you are trying to perform to your original question.